# Recovering signal after Fourier filter with Hanning window

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, fft, physics

I have a complex signal that I can see in Fourier space and would like to filter some of the frequencies I do not desire. I read online that I should apply a Hanning window before taking the fourier transform in order to avoid leakage.

Hence, what I am doing, as seen in the code below, is to apply a Hanning window to my data and then take a fourier transform of it. As a test, I wanted to see if I do not filter anything, whether I could get my original signal back. However, the signal has gone to zero at the edges.

Now, I understand this is coming from the fact that the Hanning window filter also goes to zero at its end. In that case, how do I apply the Hanning window, go to frequency domain and come back to my time domain with my signal recovered? If my signal goes to zero at the ends, when I try to filter the frequencies I desire, the result in the time domain will still go to zero at the edges.

What am I missing/ doing wrong in my method? Thank you for any help provided!

Here is a sample code of what I am doing:

```
import sys
import matplotlib
def fourier(time,array):

    fft = np.fft.fft(array*np.hanning(len(array)))

    Npts = len(array)
    spacing_array = time[::-1][:-1][::-1] - time[:-1]

    if np.mean(spacing_array) - spacing_array[0] > 1.e-16:
            print "time axis not equally separated. cannot compute fft"
            sys.exit()
    spacing = spacing_array[0]

    freq = np.fft.fftfreq(Npts, spacing)

    return freq,fft

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # generate a sample signal
    sample_rate = 100.0
    nsamples = int(2.e3)
    t = np.arange(nsamples) / sample_rate
    x = np.cos(2*np.pi*0.5*t) + 0.2*np.sin(2*np.pi*2.5*t+0.1) + \
            0.2*np.sin(2*np.pi*15.3*t) + 0.1*np.sin(2*np.pi*16.7*t + 0.1) + \
                0.1*np.sin(2*np.pi*23.45*t+.8)
    y = np.cos(7*np.pi*1.1*t) + 3*np.sin(0.2*np.pi*2.8*t+1) + \
            0.2*np.sin(8*np.pi*2.7*t) + 1*np.sin(2*np.pi*t + 2.1) + \
                0.1*np.sin(0.2*np.pi*0.45*t+1.4)
    z = x*np.exp(y*1j)

    z_freq,z_fft = fourier(t,z)

    plt.clf()
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,12))

    plt.subplot(4,1,1) # original signal
    plt.plot(t,np.absolute(z))

    plt.subplot(4,1,2) # fourier transform
    plt.semilogy(sorted(z_freq),[b for (a,b) in sorted(zip(z_freq,np.absolute(z_fft)/nsamples))])

    # filtering
    plt.subplot(4,1,3)
    idx = np.where(np.abs(z_freq)>2.0)
    z_fft[idx]=0
    z_filter = np.fft.ifft(z_fft)
    plt.plot(t,np.real(z_filter))

    z_freq,z_fft = fourier(t,z_filter)
    plt.subplot(4,1,4)
    plt.semilogy(sorted(z_freq),[b for (a,b) in sorted(zip(z_freq,np.absolute(z_fft)/nsamples))])
    plt.show()
```

And the image that comes out of it is the following:
[Real space and Frequency space of signal before and after filtering with Hanning window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lKdd.png)

Comment: Normally frequency domain filtering is implemented using overlapping blocks and either the [overlap-add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap–add_method) or [overlap-save](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap–save_method) technique for linear convolution.

Answer (score 2):

## A stab at a few of your questions.

> In that case, how do I apply the Hanning window, go to frequency domain and come back to my time domain with my signal recovered?

Up to the numerical precision of your numpy's fft implementation, applying a fourier transform and then an inverse fourier transform should return back the original signal. However, if you multiply the signal by a hanning window before the fft, the result of fft'ing and ifft'ing will be the **signal times the hanning window**. Therefore the third plot you have provided makes sense. It is the original signal, multiplied by the hanning window (and smoothed by eliminating frequencies higher than 2.0).

> I read online that I should apply a Hanning window before taking the fourier transform in order to avoid leakage.

The hanning window is used to possibly minimize spectral leakage. In an ideal case, you could use your finite clip of data as a tile to recreate the entire function throughout all space. When your finite clip of data cannot exactly serve that purpose you will incur some amount of spectral leakage.

A hanning window attenuates the beginning and end of the signal to help satisfy the "repeating tile" constraint. That being said, I don't think spectral leakage is an issue on the data you've provided, but perhaps it is in another data set that you are analyzing.

For more information on spectral leakage, go to [why does spectral leakage arise in a fft](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10120/why-does-spectral-leakage-arise-in-an-fft).

> If my signal goes to zero at the ends, when I try to filter the frequencies I desire, the result in the time domain will still go to zero at the edges.

This is not necessarily the case. It could that the frequencies you eliminate in frequency domain were actually the modes that brought the function to zero in the time domain.

## The fourth plot

Your fourth plot is interesting. In it, you are plotting the result of the fourier transform of the high-frequency eliminated time series. The function quickly decays at +/- 2 because you've eliminated those frequencies. The fact that the fft doesn't go to exactly 0 is because the discrete fourier transform isn't exact.

## Quick coding comment

One line of your code has an interesting use of array slicing. It took me a second but I wanted to comment on what you've done.

```
time[::-1][:-1][::-1] # Reverse array, disregard "new" last element, ...
                      # ... then reverse again
time[1:]  # Don't consider the first element.
time[1:] == time[::-1][:-1][::-1] # These are exactly the same.
# Result: True
```